# Binding knockout On Ajax Driven page

Tags: ajax, knockout.js

I am building an application that is mostly using ajax calls, but the problem is that i cannot use the viewmodel in the ajax driven page.

At my users list I have a table which contains a list of users that when clicking on edit button, Ajax loads the edit page to the #edit div. Now the thing is that I cannot get the vm values in the  after the new page loads in it.

```
ko.applyBindings(vm);

<div id="users">

</div>

<div id="edit">

</div> 

   this.EditAjax = function (user) {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                data:'',
                url: '/Users/Edit/'+ user.id,

                success: function (h) {
                    $('#edit').html(h);
                }
            });
        };
```

Comment: Can you please update your code to show the view model and let us see what you have tried and what is not working?  As it stands I can't tell why you can't use the view model, as you can easily reside your AJAX calls in your view model or reference your view model from outside of it as well.

Comment: Can you show an example of the html that is returned?  The problem that is breaking the bindings is that your returned HTML is not binding to the bindings you create, they are in essence breaking them.  If you have KO bindings in the returned HTML you may need to re-call ko.applyBindings from your AJAX call, although that is not a great solution.  Do you already have a full user and it's editable attributes before you make the AJAX call?

Comment: I will return a user info only which will be like 
  <p data-bind="text: UserName"></p>

Comment: Make it easy on yourself - if you already have their user name just make an edit html div that you edit the value.  Let me make a quick fiddle

Comment: I even cant get a single data bind i use a blank Html page which includes only the 
  <p data-bind="text: streetAdderess"></p>
 this statement in it thats it all even this is not working

Comment: Check the fiddle in my answer.  If you already have the username (which it sounds like you do) just set another observable equal to that object, and it will update on edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out that when we try to applybings to a div it is ok but whenever we load a ajax driven page to that div our binding are not in action anymore inside that div.This solves the problem. The thing done is to apply the bindings to the specific div after the page loads by using .then of $.ajax.

```
function ajax() {
$.ajax({
    url: "/Home/Go",
    type: 'POST',
    success: function (h) {

        $('#sam').html(h);

    },
    error: function (m) {
        alert(m);
    }

})
.then(function () {

   ko.applyBindings(AppViewModel, document.getElementById("mm"));


});
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this fiddle -

http://jsfiddle.net/p6WjJ/

You can easily bind the edit view to a Knockout observable.

```
<div id="users" data-bind="foreach: users">
    <span data-bind="text: name, click: editUser"></span>
</div>

<div id="edit" data-bind="with: editingUser">
    <input type="text" data-bind="value: name" />
</div>
```

and in your view model

```
var editingUser = ko.observable();
var users = ko.observableArray();

function editUser(sender) {
    // If you already have all of your properties of User why not just set the editor to that instead of making another server call through AJAX?
    editingUser(sender);
}
```

Comment: I tried it. I works only when the page loads. But after calling the ajax func. and load the page to the div it does`t recognize the data-binds

Comment: Then your AJAX is breaking your data-binds.  Post your AJAX call in your question and I will include it in the editUser function.

Comment: I tried the all the ways for the ajax but it didnt worked i will use the way that you advise thanks a lot.

Comment: Let me know if you have any issues